# How to use the same button style but different action (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi now I am working on a my portfolio site, I am trying to make a button that use the same style but want to use it for two button (1) go to some page (2) download cv. but both of them  do the action (1). I don't know how to make these two button do different job.

here is the code for Button,

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES =['btn--primary', 'btn--outline'];
const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

export const Button = ({
children, 
type, 
onClick,
buttonStyle,
buttonSize
}) => {

const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) 
? buttonStyle
: STYLES[0];

const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize)
? buttonSize
: SIZES[0];

return <Link to="/some-page" className='btn-mobile'>
    <button
    className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
    onClick={onClick}
    type={type}
    >
    {children}
    </button>
    </Link>
    };
```

here is the code for two buttons

```
  <div className='hero-btns'>
            <Button className='btns' 
            buttonStyle='btn--outline'
            buttonSize='btn--large'
            >
            PORTFOLIO 
            </Button>
            <Button
            className='btns' 
            buttonStyle='btn--primary'
            buttonSize='btn--large'
            >
                DOWNLOAD CV<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
            </Button>
        </div>
```

I am working on ReactJs /create-react-app. Maybe you can recommend me an easier way.

Comment: Hello, what you can do is, you can have a unique id for both of them,  and in the onClick method you can identify them with the id and according to id you can call another respective functions

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an action as props to Button Component.

```
<Button action="/PORTFOLIO-page">
   PORTFOLIO
</Button>
<Button action="/DOWNLOAD-CV-page">
   DOWNLOAD CV
</Button>
```

And change your code for Button component to:

```
return <Link to={this.props.action}>
  <button
  >
  {children}
  </button>
 </Link>
};
```

And you can pass as many props as you want.